# Simulating Random Multiples

Tags: number-theory, statistics, simulation

I was running a statistical simulation, where I'd generate random numbers from 1 to $N$, where $N$ varies from 1 to $10^6$. I would keep generating random numbers until the current random number was a multiple of one of the previous numbers. For example:

---

If $N = 10$

$5, 8, 6, 7, 10$ -> We stop at 10 because it's a multiple of 5. Total count is 5

$10, 2, 4$ -> We stop at 4 because it's a multiple of 2. Total count is 3

---

For each $N$, I ran 1000 trials and averaged the total count for each range. I came up with the following graph, which is almost like a square root equation:

[image: graph]

Why does it start to converge to what seems like some constant * $\sqrt{N}$? Does anyone have a mathematical explanation for this trend occurring?

Upon using a fit line of y = Ax^0.5, I have A to be 0.4486 and a correlation of 0.9970.

[image: graph2]

Edit: I coded this in C++ [here](https://github.com/PulseBeat02/ap-statistics-simulation-project/blob/main/main.cpp) for any coders out there.

Comment: ```const int min = trial;``` With this, you are not generating random from 1 to N

Comment: @DanielMathias Oops -- must have messed up while porting from Java to C++ code Let me rerun the fixed simulation and see what I get.

Comment: I just updated the graphs. The values are a bit more off now but the correlation is still very high for the Ax^0.5 fit.

Comment: Agreed, but the ratio is still [trending downward](https://pastebin.com/BSi3uEDB) up to $N=10^6$ For larger $N$ (possibly much larger) the ratio seems likely to drop below $0.4$

Comment: Note: The data in my pastebin was generated by my own code, with 100,000 sample runs for each N.

Comment: Interesting question  :)  I think the order of growth will be smaller than $\sqrt N$; for one thing, $\sqrt N$ is the expected order of growth if we generate random numbers until the current one is *equal* to one of the previous ones (that's the birthday paradox)! On the other hand, maybe it's not that much smaller: the expected number of multiples of each chosen number is about $\log N$, as is the expected number of divisors of the last chosen number. So maybe the true order of growth is $\sqrt N/\log N$?

Comment: Are you allowed to have repeated numbers in the list? And does a repeat end the process?

Comment: @paw88789 The repeat would end the process, so there wouldn't be any duplicate numbers (for example, 1, 3, 5, 5 would end because 5 is a multiple of 5).

Comment: I made a Gist with a CSV that has around ~15k datapoints here if someone wants to work with some data: https://gist.github.com/PulseBeat02/9c1df3cca875c8565b89b449499a6e5f